# Не совсем понимаю как работают колбэки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

Экспериментировал с колбэками, обнаружил следующее в своем коде:

```
function doSomething(subject, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {console.log(`Hi, ${subject}`);}, 3000);
    callback();
}
doSomething('John', function() {
    console.log('Finish');
});
```

Я поставил **setTimeout**, предположив, что сначала отработаются эти 3 секунды, а потом только выполнится функция **calback()**. Однако у меня **Finish** отобразился раньше чем **Hi, John**. Почему так произошло?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему так произошло?

Потому что `setTimeout` асинхронная функция. К колбэкам это не имеет никакого отношения.

Если банально написать вместо таймаута строку `console.log(1+2)`, то вначале она выполнится, а потом колбэк

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое